# web farm application issue with compilation

Tags: asp.net, webfarm

I have an application in a web farm which it consists of 4 web servers.
Every time I made a change on the application and I upload it on the server I am getting an error which said that the *.DLL isn't available. 
It gets compiled on the 1st server and I have to await until it gets compiled on the other servers as well.

Let's say that I have 50 web servers, how could I avoid the compilation an all the servers.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could write a PowerShell script to automate cross-farm compilation.

Comment: could you suggest anything of how could this be applied?